# cannot approve contract to ERC-20 token due to ProviderError: HttpProviderError error

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, erc20

OracleSwap is a DEX that is a fork of Uniswap.

The end goal is I am trying to add liquidity
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-01#addliquidity

In order to do this, first we need to approve the OracleSwapRouter contract to spend the erc20 token.

I get below error when I am trying to `approve` to `OracleSwapRouter` in songbird (EVM compatible) network so that I can provide liquidity on the farm. I am not sure if this is an RPC rate-limiting issue or if something is wrong with the code.

```
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (<path>/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (<path>/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:181:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (<path>/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

**Relevant links**

**oracle erc20 token**
--> https://songbird-explorer.flare.network/address/0xD7565b16b65376e2Ddb6c71E7971c7185A7Ff3Ff

**contract to approve (OracleSwapRouter)**
--> https://songbird-explorer.flare.network/address/0x73E93D9657E6f32203f900fe1BD81179a5bf6Ce4

Below are the relevant code snippets

```
  const OracleSwapRouterContract = await ethers.getContractAt(OracleSwapRouterAbi.default,
"0x73E93D9657E6f32203f900fe1BD81179a5bf6Ce4");

const oracleContract = await ethers.getContractAt(oracleAbi.default,  "0xd7565b16b65376e2ddb6c71e7971c7185a7ff3ff");

 await oracleContract.approve(
      "0x73E93D9657E6f32203f900fe1BD81179a5bf6Ce4",
      oracleBalance
    );
```

The below code gives me the balance for the account so I know oracleContract is not the problem.

```
  const oracleBalance = await oracleContract.balanceOf(SONGBIRD_ACC);
```

my hardhat network config

```
songbird: {
      url: "https://songbird-api.flare.network/ext/C/rpc",
      chainId: 19,
      accounts:
        SONGBIRD_PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [SONGBIRD_PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
      gasPrice: 900000000,
    },
```

Comment: Hmm.... let's focus in on that error. Does the oracleContract have an approve function?

Comment: Hi @PatrickCollins, sorry. for the late reply.
Yes, the oracleContract does have an approve function.
as you can see here --> https://songbird-explorer.flare.network/address/0xD7565b16b65376e2Ddb6c71E7971c7185A7Ff3Ff/write-contract#address-tabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some lines to `node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/providers/http.js` to debug. After every `isErrorResponse` check, add: `console.log(response)` or `console.log(jsonRpcResponse)`.

Most likely it's an error inside your contracts or deploy script (or both).

Comment: Thank you @ruarin. I tried this and I got some helpful errors that I could actually work with. 
Now I have another problem that is not directly related. 
I will try to solve this one and let you know if I am able to resolve the first problem

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem with your help. 
Although what you mentioned is not the direct problem to the solution. It has helped me immensely in figuring out the actual problem.