# Solidity Deployment Error - "ProviderError: HttpProviderError"

Tags: http, solidity, rpc

Been attempting to deploy a new instance of a contract I've deployed before, from an environment I haven't used in a while (though which has successfully deployed before). None of the details of the contracts or my configuration have changed, and it appears that the http error is unrelated. What can I do to debug and resolve?

```
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:187:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider._getChainIdFromEthNetVersion (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:33:17)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider._getChainId (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:17:25)
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider.request (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/chainId.ts:55:29)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
    at getSigners (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:45:20)
    at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (/home/user/Solidity/env/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:288:21)
    at main (/home/user/Solidity/env/scripts/deployVerify.js:6:27)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Found some great advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74842616/14111336

Turns out my Alchemy RPC app had ceased working. I reset to a new app, and worked immediately as intended.